# Re-gain user authorization after scope change in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE app that requires end user credential to call Google Cloud APIs. I use the oauth2 decorator and it worked well in my first version. However, in my second version, I added another scope so that I can call another Cloud API.

I changed my codes and re-deployed the app. However, the web app didn't ask me to re-authorize, and I got the 403 response with the message: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." My teammate tested the app for me, and she was asked to authorize the correct new scope, so I guess the problem the app is still using the old scope for me.

How could I make the app re-prompt the consent form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer from a coworker. Wanna post it here if any one needs it.

"A user can revoke access by visiting [Account Settings](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions)".